# Butterworth Filter RLC LPF

Tags: filter, low-pass, passive-filter

I was trying to construct a second order passive Butterworth filter using the circuit below:

[image]

The specification required the load \$R\$ to be 1 ohm and cut-off frequency to be at 1 rad/s. I derived the transfer function to be:

$$V_\text{out}(s) = \frac{1}{1 + sL/R + s^2 LC}V_\text{in}$$

Butterworth filter requires the 3 dB point to be on the corner frequency which is given by: $$F_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}}$$

I do not know how to choose the values of \$C\$ and \$L\$ to match all these requirements. What is the mathematical proof to obtain the answers?

Comment: Realize your question is academic and that in practice you use a table for a LC values. You can find what complex poles you need here https://2n3904blog.com/butterworth-filter/

Comment: Ashad, if you are done with this now please formally accept my answer else, if you still need something clarifying then leave a comment under my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A butterworth filter has a damping ratio (zeta or \$\zeta\$) of 0.7071 and this is the missing piece of your jigsaw. So rearrange your TF to be like this: -

\$\dfrac{V_O}{V_I}=\dfrac{\frac{1}{LC}}{s^2+\frac{s}{CR}+\frac{1}{LC}}
\$

This is now of the standard form where \$2\zeta\omega_n= \frac{1}{CR}\$ and \$\frac{1}{LC}=\omega_n^2\$.

So now you have a way to calculate C because you know \$\omega_n\$ and you now know what \$\zeta\$ is for a butterworth filter (of any order).